# Turning boolean into a message?

Tags: java

This program takes a users password and tell them if they have a valid password. The password needs 6-10 characters, which contain at least 1 number and letter. I get user input in my PasswordUI class. My Password class uses that to check if the password is valid and returns a boolean. How do I take that boolean and use it to form a message that I will use in my PasswordUI class?

```
public class PasswordUI extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("");
    JTextField inputBox = new JTextField(40);
    JButton goButton = new JButton("Go");
    Container con = getContentPane();

    public void init()
    {
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        con.add(new JLabel("Enter a password between 6-10 characters. Must contain atleast 1 number and 1 letter"));
        con.add(inputBox);
        con.add(goButton);
        con.add(passwordLabel);

        goButton.addActionListener(this);
        inputBox.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String userInput = inputBox.getText();

        boolean pass= Password.check(userInput);
        //String message = Password.display(null);
        Password mess= new Password();

        passwordLabel.setText( mess.getDisplay());



    }
}

public class Password {


    public static boolean check(String str)
    {

    boolean result = false;
    char ch;
    int letterCount = 0,
            digitCount= 0 ;
    int length = str.length();

    if(str.length()>= 6)

    {
        if(str.length()<= 10)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++ ) //i<end 
            {
                ch = str.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                    digitCount++;
                else if (Character.isLetter(ch))
                    letterCount++;
            }

            if (letterCount >= 1 && digitCount >= 1)
                result = true;

            }
        }
    return result;
    }


    public String getDisplay()//how do I do this?

    {
        String message = result ? "Your password is valid" : "You Password is invalid"; 
//result isn't working


        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Are there exceptions? If so, post a complete stack trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn a boolean into a message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041481/how-to-turn-a-boolean-into-a-message)

Comment: I just realized that you re-posted your question. I was aware that I had seen it somewhere, and I found it. I answered the it there already(along with the new edit). Please don't create duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the boolean variable `result` into the `getDisplay()` method.

```
public static String getDisplay(boolean result) {         
    return result ? "Your password is valid" : "You Password is invalid";
}
```

Comment: result is in `public **static** boolean check(String str)`, you would have to instantiate a new Password to call `getDisplay()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your actionPerformed you receive the result of the password check, but you call getDisplay on a new Password mess.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String userInput = inputBox.getText();

        boolean pass= Password.check(userInput);
        //String message = Password.display(null);
        Password mess= new Password();

        passwordLabel.setText( mess.getDisplay());
    }
```

This would solve your problem:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String userInput = inputBox.getText();

        boolean pass= Password.check(userInput);
        //String message = Password.display(null);
        **//**Password mess= new Password();

        passwordLabel.setText(**pass**);
    }
```

---

I do, however, suggest you restructure your Password class. Make it have a field `String pass`, then simply **override toString()** and make it return (String) check(pass).

Comment: Also, don't make check() static.

Comment: All this does is displays a true or false. I want to display getDisplay.

Comment: @Marcus Put your `getDisplay()` code in `toString()`. You can make it print whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is the solution to what I was trying to do

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String userInput = inputBox.getText();
        Password mess= new Password();//**added this
        boolean pass= mess.check(userInput);//**used this
        passwordLabel.setText(mess.getDisplay(pass));//**changed this



    }
    }
public  boolean check(String str) //**removed static
    {

    boolean result = false;
    char ch;
    int letterCount = 0,
            digitCount= 0 ;
    int length = str.length();

    if(str.length()>= 6)

    {
        if(str.length()<= 10)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++ ) //i<end 
            {
                ch = str.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                    digitCount++;
                else if (Character.isLetter(ch))
                    letterCount++;
            }

            if (letterCount >= 1 && digitCount >= 1)
                result = true;

            }
        }
    return result;
    }


    public String getDisplay(boolean result) //**changed this to boolean result as was suggested

    {
        String message = result ? "Your password is valid" : "You Password is invalid"; //how do I do this?


        return message;
    }
```

Comment: This is **BAD** code. If you have to instantiate a Password object just to test a given String (e.g. not testing Password object state) then use a static method and call `Password.checkPass(String s)`. **Methods** behave based on **object state**, what you have done is very **non-OO**. Imagine having to instantiate a Math object before being able to call add(1,2) -- it's silly and unneeded